# How to minimize repetitive code inside a function in JS

Tags: javascript

I have this line of code from each function of my carousel interface: `dots[(i+len-1)%len].className = dots[(i+len-1)%len].className.replace(" active", "")` It removes the previous class "active" on every iteration of dot elements. If i do not add this code on each function, class "active" propagates by more than one on each iteration like this: `<span class="dot active active active active" onclick="dotSlide(1)"></span>` It's a bug, during the slide of the carousel or when i press next or prev button the active dot is not align with the image by its corresponding index. How can i reduce this codes.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
loop();
var slides, dots;

function loop() {
  slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  var len = dots.length;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    dots[(i + len - 1) % len].className = dots[(i + len - 1) % len].className.replace(" active", "")

    dots[(i + len - 2) % len].className = dots[(i + len - 2) % len].className.replace(" active", "");
    dots[(i + len - 3) % len].className = dots[(i + len - 3) % len].className.replace(" active", "")
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(loop, 6000); // Change image every 6 seconds
}

function plusSlides(position) {
  var len = dots.length;
  slideIndex += position;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  } else if (slideIndex < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    dots[(i + len - 1) % len].className = dots[(i + len - 1) % len].className.replace(" active", "");
    dots[(i + len - 2) % len].className = dots[(i + len - 2) % len].className.replace(" active", "")
    dots[(i + len - 3) % len].className = dots[(i + len - 3) % len].className.replace(" active", "")
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  }
}

function dotSlide(index) {
  if (index > slides.length) {
    index = 1
  } else if (index < 1) {
    index = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  var len = dots.length;
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    dots[(i + len - 1) % len].className = dots[(i + len - 1) % len].className.replace(" active", "");
    dots[(i + len - 2) % len].className = dots[(i + len - 2) % len].className.replace(" active", "")
    dots[(i + len - 3) % len].className = dots[(i + len - 3) % len].className.replace(" active", "")
    slides[index - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[index - 1].className += " active";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slide">
  <div class="slides-container" style="text-align:center">
    <div class="slides fadeOut"> <img src="images/pine_forest.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="slides fadeOut"> <img src="images/best-forest.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="slides fadeOut"> <img src="images/EarthBeauty221.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="slides fadeOut"> <img src="images/setwalls.ru-79192.jpg"> </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dots" style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="dotSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="dotSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="dotSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="dotSlide(4)"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual solutions apply, in this case, utility functions and loops. First, the utility function:

```
// NOTE: We'll come back to this function, it has potential issues
function removeSubsequentClass(element, cls) {
  element.className = element.className.replace(" " + cls, "");
}
```

Then at a minimum you have:

```
removeSubsequentClass(dots[(i+len-1)%len], "active");
removeSubsequentClass(dots[(i+len-2)%len], "active");
removeSubsequentClass(dots[(i+len-3)%len], "active");
```

It also has the advantage of encapsulating that functionality, which will be useful in a moment.

That's already an improvement, but we can also throw a loop at it:

```
for (let n = 1; n <= 3; ++n) {
    removeSubsequentClass(dots[(i+len-n)%len], "active");
}
```

---

About `removeSubsequentClass`: It's quite fragile. It assumes that:

- The class won't be the *first* class
- The class won't be a substring of another class (consider: `class="foo active-nifty-thing"`, which would become`class="foo-nifty-thing"` -- oops!)

On any modern browser, you can use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) (which can be polyfilled) instead. We can also remove the qualification from the name:

```
// NOTE: We'll come back to this function, it has potential issues
function removeClass(element, cls) {
  element.classList.remove(cls);
}
```

if you need to support obsolete browsers without `classList` and don't want to polyfill, then:

```
function removeClass(element, cls) {
  element.className = (" " + element.className + " ")
    .replace(" " + cls + " ", "")
    .replace(/(?:^ +)|(?: +$)/g, "");
}
```

If you want to do it with one `replace` and promise that your classes won't include any characters that are treated specially by regular expressions, then:

```
function removeClass(element, cls) {
  element.className = (" " + element.className + " ")
    .replace(new RegExp("(?:^ +)|(?: +$)|(?: " + cls + " )", "g"), "");
}
```

or use a [regular expression escape function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) if the class names may not be safe for the above:

```
function removeClass(element, cls) {
  element.className = (" " + element.className + " ")
    .replace(new RegExp("(?:^ +)|(?: +$)|(?: " + theEscapeFunctionGoesHere(cls) + " )", "g"), "");
}
```